# Split row into multilple rows on sql server 2008R2 (no pivot or unpivot is available)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would you split this row into multplie rowa  (in Sql Server 2008R2 not able to use pivot or unpivot) 
 a single row

```
Entity|Trans Type   |    S100   |       S50          
Test1 , Start Balance ,50000.00  , 25000.00
```

To multiple rows

```
 Entity|  Trans Type|     Denom|    S100 |       S50       
Test1,  Start Balance   ,100 ,    50000.00  ,0           
Test1,  Start Balance   ,50,      0  ,       25000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` or `outer apply`:

```
select t.entity, t.transtype, v.*
from t outer apply
     (values (100, S100, 0), (50, 0, S50)) v(denom, S100, S50);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution.

```
SELECT [Entity], [Trans Type], 100 [Denom], [S100], 0 [S50]  
FROM TheTable 
UNION ALL 
SELECT [Entity], [Trans Type], 50 [Denom], 0 [S100], [S50]  
FROM TheTable
```